# IFrame method .getBody returns null

Tags: javascript, java, iframe, gwt, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in GWT project, Where i am using 4 CKEditor into single UI. On change of dropDown am changing values of thod CKEditor textFields.

```
IFrameElement iframe = (IFrameElement) element;
iframe.getContentDocument().getBody().setInnerText(value);
```

Here `iframe.getContentDocument()` returns **Document** , But `iframe.getContentDocument().getBody()` reutrns null.

Where on first two ckeditor `iframe.getContentDocument().getBody()` , they perfectly working, but for the next two, 
    `iframe.getContentDocument().getBody()` reutrns null. Hence getting error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at DOMImplWebkit_1_g$.setInnerText_2_g$ [as setInnerText_6_g$]....

Comment: What is "element" and how you create it ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski I have my own javascript code, which return element and i store it to *NodeList<com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element>

Comment: @NielsNet I know how to implement, your help would be much appreciated if you could give any valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are somewhere setting value as blank ("") for handling null pointer issues.

Comment: yes thanks. I got it now, that i was calling a method which set all textArea default value.